# How to call MasterPage from c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my asp.net project I have a MasterPage and an extra C# class called `Resources.cs`. In MasterPage I have a modal which I'm trying to use to show error messages. The way I show modals from backcode is:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "PopModal", scriptModal, true);
```

Ths first `this` references the page where script will execute and I don't know how to reference my MasterPage from `Resources.cs`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Master page if you want to use ScriptManager in a class.

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "PopModal", scriptModal, true);
```

Comment: You're right, this worked. Thanks! but here's another problem. There's a page called ```ProductsMain``` (this page is in the content placeholder of masterpage) but in ```ProductsMain``` I have an iframe which display another screen Called ```Products```. Your code doesn't work in this ```Products``` because it doesn't have MasterPage. Do you know how can I solve it?

Comment: This code works with or without a Master Page. You just call it from wherever you want.